# Can't Delete AMSIExt.dll

Tags: windows-10, dll

I have been trying to delete AMSIExt.dll but I'm stuck. I tried googling the issue but I didn't find any fix. 
This file comes from McAfee Inc, the file description is "McAfee Cloud AV Third Party Ext"\

Here is what I tried to do:
First I tried to right click the file and delete, but I got an error saying the file is open in Google Chrome.
I closed Google Chrome and tried again, but then I got an error saying that the file is open in Windows Explorer.
I tried restarting Windows Explorer and deleting it, but now I'm getting an error saying that I can't complete the action since this file is open in Windows Management Instrumentation.
I tried deleting the file using force delete in command prompt but I got an error saying "Access denied"

Anything you guys recommend?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried deleting it in safe mode?

Comment: I assume has an Administrator on the machine you have tried the McAfee uninstall tool?